# How can I cycle through all Fill-In Form Fields, skipping Check Boxes, and change them all to Regular Text?

Tags: vba, checkbox, ms-word, form-fields, word-2016

To clarify, my company works with Microsoft Word 2016 Applications that are covered in Fill-In Form Fields in addition to Check Boxes. The Form Fields can have Numbers, Dates and just Regular Text as shown below:

[Test Form Field Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiH5L.png)

We have already created a macro to eliminate the Help Text in each FormField, due to a new SOP, throughout the active document as shown below:

```
Sub FillInHelpRemoval()
Dim fld As FormField
    For Each fld In ActiveDocument.FormFields
            fld.StatusText = ""
    Next
End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is trying to figure out how to add to the macro above a way to cycle through each Form Field, skipping Check Boxes, changing each one of them to have the attributes below...

```
TextInput.EditType Type:=wdRegularText, Default:="", Format:=""
```

...no matter if the **TextInput.EditType Type** is **wdNumberText** or **wdDateText**.

This would help eliminate many more clicks and steps needed to process our work.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my supervisor came up with a code that works for our needs, however, all of the included code may not be necessary for the execution of the macro, but he's afraid to remove anything. LOL!

But I will include it here for those who are looking for similar VBA resolutions in the future, or even those who can clarify it and reduce the coding clutter.

```
Sub FillInHelpRemoval()

Dim objFld As FormField
Dim intCount, intLoop As Integer
Dim intNum, intText, intDate, intCheck As Integer
Dim intLen As Integer
Dim intLoop2 As Integer
Dim lngStr As Long


For Each objFld In ActiveDocument.FormFields
     intCount = intCount + 1
Next

If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then ActiveDocument.Unprotect

On Error Resume Next
For intLoop = 1 To intCount
    Select Case True
    Case ActiveDocument.FormFields(intLoop).Type = 70 'text
        ActiveDocument.FormFields(intLoop).Select

        If ActiveDocument.FormFields(intLoop).TextInput.Type = wdDateText Then
             ActiveDocument.FormFields(intLoop).Select
            With Selection.FormFields(1)

                With .TextInput
                    .EditType Type:=wdRegularText, Default:="", Format:=""
                End With

            End With

            intDate = intDate + 1
        Else
            If ActiveDocument.FormFields(intLoop).TextInput.Type = wdNumberText Then
                 ActiveDocument.FormFields(intLoop).Select
                With Selection.FormFields(1)

                    With .TextInput
                        .EditType Type:=wdRegularText, Default:="", Format:=""
                    End With
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            End With
                intNum = intNum + 1

            End If
        End If

    Case Else
        Debug.Print ActiveDocument.FormFields(intLoop).Type
    End Select
Next intLoop

'Call FillInHelpRemoval

For Each objFld In ActiveDocument.FormFields
    objFld.Select
    With Selection.FormFields(1)
        .StatusText = ""
    End With

    Next
End Sub
```